# Copy to Clipboard Issue

Tags: shiny

I am trying to add copy to clipboard functionality in shiny app. It works on second try. When I click on the button first time, it does not copy the content, starts copying from the second time. It seems to be a bug. I tried another package `rclipboard`, this does not work on shinyapps.io and also having some other erratic issues.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyCopy2clipboard)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Setup
  use_copy(),
  
  # Text Input 1
  textInput("text", "Enter Your Text"),
  
  # Copy Button 1
  CopyButton(
    "copybtn",
    "Copy to Clipboard",
    icon = icon("copy"),
    text = "No Text Found",
    class = "btn-primary",
    width = "150px"
  )
  
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    
    req(input$copybtn)
    CopyButtonUpdate(session,
                     id = "copybtn",
                     label = "Copy to Clipboard",
                     icon = icon("copy"),
                     text = input$text
    )
    
  })
  
}

# Run App
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It works if you remove `req(input$copybtn)`, but I'm not sure why...